# Why can't I capture this by-reference ('&this') in lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I understand the correct way to capture `this` (to modify object properties) in a lambda is as follows:

```
auto f = [this] () { /* ... */ };
```

But I'm curious as to the following peculiarity I've seen:

```
class C {
    public:
        void foo() {
            // auto f = [] () { // this not captured
            auto f = [&] () { // why does this work?
            // auto f = [&this] () { // Expected ',' before 'this'
            // auto f = [this] () { // works as expected
                x = 5;
            };
            f();
        }

    private:
        int x;
};
```

The oddity that I am confused by (and would like answered) is why the following works:

```
auto f = [&] () { /* ... */ }; // capture everything by reference
```

And why I cannot explicitly capture `this` by reference:

```
auto f = [&this] () { /* ... */ }; // a compiler error as seen above.
```

Comment: Why would you _want_ to? In terms of things for which a reference to a pointer might ever conceivably be useful: `this` can't be changed, it isn't large enough to make a reference faster... and **anyway**, _it doesn't actually exist_, so it has no real lifetime, meaning any reference to it would be dangling by definition. `this` is a prvalue, not an lvalue.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The reason `[&this]` doesn't work is because it is a syntax error.  Each comma-seperated parameter in the `lambda-introducer` is a `capture`:

```
capture:
    identifier
    & identifier
    this
```

You can see that `&this` isn't allowed syntactically.  The reason it isn't allowed is because you would never want to capture `this` by reference, as it is a small const pointer.  You would only ever want to pass it by value - so the language just doesn't support capturing `this` by reference.

To capture `this` explicitly you can use `[this]` as the `lambda-introducer`.

The first `capture` can be a `capture-default` which is:

```
capture-default:
    &
    =
```

This means capture automatically whatever I use, by reference (`&`) or by value (`=`) respectively - however the treatment of `this` is special - in both cases it is captured by value for the reasons given previously (even with a default capture of `&`, which usually means capture by reference).

5.1.2.7/8:

> For purposes of name lookup (3.4), determining the type and value of `this` (9.3.2) and transforming id-
>   expressions referring to non-static class members into class member access expressions using `(*this)` (9.3.1),
>   the compound-statement [OF THE LAMBDA] is considered in the context of the lambda-expression.

So the lambda acts as if it is part of the enclosing member function when using member names (like in your example the use of the name `x`), so it will generate "implicit usages" of `this` just like a member function does.

> If a lambda-capture includes a capture-default that is `&`, the identifiers in the lambda-capture shall not be
>   preceded by `&`. If a lambda-capture includes a capture-default that is `=`, the lambda-capture shall not contain
>   `this` and each identifier it contains shall be preceded by `&`. An identifier or `this` shall not appear more than
>   once in a lambda-capture.

So you can use `[this]`, `[&]`, `[=]` or `[&,this]` as a `lambda-introducer` to capture the `this` pointer by value.

However `[&this]` and `[=, this]` are ill-formed.  In the last case gcc forgivingly warns for `[=,this]` that `explicit by-copy capture of ‘this’ redundant with by-copy capture default` rather than errors.

Comment: I’m wondering, is there any reason ever *not* to use either `[&]` or `[=]`? Why would I want to specify identifiers explicitly if the compiler is perfectly capable of figuring out by itself what to capture?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: What if you want to capture some things by value and others by reference? Or want to be very explicit with what you capture?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It's a safety feature.  You might accidentally capture names that you don't intend to.

Comment: @user1131467 Not sure I buy that. Why don’t other block level constructs have the same syntax then?

Comment: @Xeo Just capture all of them by reference. How bad can it be? For performance-critical applications the lambda will most likely be inlined anyway, and the reference elided. Having a dedicated syntax to specify capture has a serious disadvantage in readability; it burdens lambdas substantially. The benefits are more than questionable. This is taking “you don’t pay for what you don’t use” to foolish extremes.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Block-level constructs don't magically copy a pointer to the objects they use into a new invisible anonymous type that can then survive the enclosing scope - simply by using the objects name in an expression.  Lambda capturing is a lot more of a dangerous business.

Comment: @user1131467 Good argument, hadn’t thought about that. And yet the general recommendation among many C++ experts seems to be “just use `[&]`” which would of course completely cancel out this precaution. Let’s see what time will teach us.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'd say "use `[&]` if you are doing something like creating a block to be passed into a control structure", but explicitly capture if you are producing a lambda that is going to be used for less simple purposes.  `[&]` is a horrible idea if the lambda is going to outlive the current scope.  However, many uses of lambdas are just ways to pass blocks to control structures, and the block won't outlive the block it was created in scope.

Comment: @Yakk I wouldn’t say “horrible idea” but I get the gist.

Comment: See the C++17 update regarding this: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0018r3.html

Comment: @johnbakers Interesting, but not really related. AFAICT it's about taking a copy by value of the instance at `*this`, and redirecting bits of code saying `this->` to work on that copy. It's not about taking the pointer `this` by reference, for some unknown reason the OP never explained.

Comment: You say _`&this` isn't allowed syntactically_. But doesn't `this` match `identifier` in the syntax description you cite?

Comment: @Ruslan: No, `this` is a keyword, `this` is not an identifier.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos, it's strange to see that [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) uses the terminology that _`(*this)` [...] is always captured by reference_, instead of _`this` is always captured by value_. I've asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66534397/when-using-either-default-capture-mode-is-this-captured-by-copy-or-this-capt) to understand this detail.

Comment: @Andrew Tomazos "The reason it isn't allowed is because you would never want to capture `this` by reference, as it is a small const pointer." Could you please explain that in more detail for me? Thanks.

Comment: @John: If something is small and const then there is no point in taking a reference to it - you may as well just take a copy - as you can't modify it anyway (const), and its cheap to copy (small).  The `this` pointer is such a thing.  What do you not understand?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos I fully understand you now. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: `this` is a prvalue, so it can't have a reference.

Answer (score 7):

Because standard doesn't have `&this` in Captures lists:

**N4713 8.4.5.2 Captures:**

```
lambda-capture:
    capture-default
    capture-list
    capture-default, capture-list

capture-default:
    &
    =
capture-list:
    capture...opt
    capture-list, capture...opt
capture:
    simple-capture
    init-capture
simple-capture:
    identifier
    &identifier
    this
    * this
init-capture:
    identifier initializer
    &identifier initializer
```

> 7. For the purposes of lambda capture, an expression potentially references local entities as follows:
>
>    7.3    A this expression potentially references *this.

So, standard guarantees `this` and `*this` is valid, and `&this` is invalid. Also, capturing `this` means capturing `*this`(which is a lvalue, the object itself) **by reference**, **rather than** capturing `this` pointer **by value**!

Comment: `*this` captures the object by **value**