# Member function as a map comparator?

Tags: c++, comparator, stdmap, pointer-to-member

I know how to create a function that serves as a custom map comparator:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string, bool (*)(std::string, std::string)> myMap(MapComparator);

bool MapComparator(std::string left, std::string right)
{
    return left < right;
}
```

But I don't know how to do the same with a **member** function:

```
bool MyClass::MapComparator(std::string left, std::string right)
{
    return left < right;
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be a non-static member function? Given your example, you could just declare the member function `static` because it does not access any non-static data members.

Comment: You would probably do well to create a functor or use an outright-lambda.  And what exactly is `myMap(MapComparator)` supposed to be doing anyway?

Comment: @jogojapan **Of course, it doesnt!** Haven't thought of it though. Thx. Still, I'd like to see the syntax to use a non-static member function, if possible.
@WhozCraig For some reasons I prefer a member function to a functor. And I'm using VS2010 which I'm not sure supports lambdas. `myMap(MapComparator)` was in my class's initializer list, I fixed the example code.

Comment: @NPS well you shouldn't prefer it. A member requires, among other things a `this` pointer, which cannot be supplied at *compile* time (map comparators aren't used like comparators for `std::sort`). Secondly, even if you use a static or global function, function *pointers* make *lousy* comparators. They don't inline worth a damn, whereas a *type* (such as a lambda or functor) that appropriately exposes the function operator does so quite nicely (usually, anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

**In C++11 you can use a lambda:**

```
std::map<std::string, std::string, bool (*)(std::string, std::string)> myMap(
    [](string lhs, int rhs){ // You may need to put [this] instead of [] to capture the enclosing "this" pointer.
       return MapComparator(lhs, rhs); // Or do the comparison inline
    });
```

**If the function is static, use `::` syntax:**

```
class MyClass {
public:
    static bool MyClass::MapComparator(std::string left, std::string right);
};
...
std::map<std::string, std::string, bool (*)(std::string, std::string)> myMap(MyClass::MapComparator);
```

If the function is non-static, make a static wrapper, member or non-member, and call a member function from it.

Comment: +1 for the answer in general, and particularly for the `[this]` capture.

Comment: Does `[this]` work? I didn't know you could cast a capturing lambda function to a function pointer.

Comment: @Jacob Yes, it is allowed (see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16323032/335858)).