# QtConcurrent.run() with a c++11 lambda that captures a reference to "this" to emit signal

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, lambda, qtconcurrent

While this works, I have this strange feeling my QObject emit is not threadsafe and the fact that this hasn't exploded yet is just luck.

```
void LoginController::attemptLogin(QString username, QString password)
{
    emit loginAttemptStatus(QString("Connecting to service..."));
    QFuture<bool> future = QtConcurrent::run([&](QString username, QString password){
            // fake a long running operation
            QThread::sleep(1);
            emit loginAttemptStatus(QString("Connected to service..."));
            // a dumb test login
            QString u("asdf");
            bool success = username.compare( u ) == 0;
            if ( success ) {
                emit loginAttemptStatus(QString("Success..."));
            } else {
                emit loginAttemptStatus(QString("Failure..."));
            }
            return success;
    }, username, password);
    this->watchLoginAttempt.setFuture(future);
}
```

So, does capturing a reference to `this` going to cause problems?

Because I think it is but I cannot find a definitive answer.

Comment: `this` is never captured by reference, it can only be captured by value ([See "this" question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323032/capturing-of-this-in-lambda?rq=1) [Get it, "this" question?!?]).

Comment: That makes sense otherwise we would need like some double dereference operator lol "this-->"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only case when it can explode, is when you destroy `LoginController` before lambda expression ends. Proper handling of `watchLoginAttempt` (`future`) should prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

emitting is thread-safe as long as the connections to the slots are not `QT::DirectConnection` or `QT::BlockingQueuedConnection` [where there may be issues with different threads](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads)

`connect` uses `Qt::AutoConnection` by default which ensure the correct action is taken no matter which thread does the emitting