# Failed to call class member function in C++ lambda expression

Tags: c++, lambda

```
//==== 1 ====
string func1(string x1, string x2){
    return x1 + x2;
}
auto lambda1 = [](string x1, string x2){cout << func1(x1,x2);};

//==== 2 ====
class Test{
public:
    string func2(string x1, string x2){
        return x1 + x2;
    }
    void tst(){
        auto lambda2 = [](string x1, string x2){cout << func2(x1,x2);};
    }
};
```

lambda1 is right.
But lambda2 got an error (under g++ 4.8):

```
error: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function
         auto lambda2 = [](string x1, string x2){cout << func2(x1,x2);};
```

What's the right way to call a member function in lambda?

Comment: The error mentions capturing `this`. Reading about lambda captures is a good start.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323032/capturing-of-this-in-lambda

Comment: Please, do not put the answer in the question - post it as *answer to your question*.

Comment: Answers go in the box below. You're allowed to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler gives you the answer you are looking for:

> error: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function

You need to provide a `this` capture inside `[]` brackets:

```
auto lambda2 = [this](string x1, string x2){cout << func2(x1,x2);};
```

Without it, the compiler would not know the context of the variables. Note that both `x1` and `x2` will be copied.

Read more on lambda captures [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture).

Answer (score 0):

In the `lambda` function under `Test::tst()`, you have a call to `func2`. That call cannot be completed unless `this` is captured by the `lambda` function.

```
void tst(){
    auto lambda2 = [this](string x1, string x2){cout << this->func2(x1,x2);};
}
```

should do it.