# Passing controls as member fields to a method called with the new connect()

Tags: c++, qt, lambda

I have a question regarding the new `connect()` syntax of qt.

My connect looks like this:

```
connect(m_ui->addEntryButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [&](){HandleSignalEvents(Events::AddEntryButton);});
```

with `m_ui->addEntryButton` as my triggering pushbutton and the lambda calling a method, which would then go and redirect the signal depending on its enum parameter to the actual handling method.

However, the problem I have, is that my HandleSignalEvents method looks like this:

```
void UIController::HandleSignalEvents(Events event)
{
    switch (event)
    {
    case Events::AddEntryButton:
        m_eventHandler.HandleAddEntryClick(m_ui->addEntryDateEdit, m_ui->addEntryTextEdit, m_ui->mainEntryList);
        break;
    }

}
```

I think the content is pretty much not too relevant in detail, I just want to make sure that you guys understand, that I want to pass pointers to my UI controls to the function, so I can perform all my actions there, including resetting text fields etc.

However, I can't quite figure out how to deal with the scope issue, considering the function is called from a lambda. I tried to capture `this`, and then passing the whole ui pointer to the HandleSignalEvent function, but all I ever end with is a memory access violation assertion.

However, I would really like to do it the lambda way, as I otherwise would have to setup SignalMappers or some other fuzzy stuff.

Is there any advice on how to properly pass the correct handles?

I should note that my ui pointer is a `boost::shared_ptr`.

EDIT:

Here is some additional code, as requested:

My controller:

```
void UIController::InitBinds()
{
    connect(m_ui->addEntryButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [&](){HandleSignalEvents(Events::AddEntryButton); });
}

void UIController::HandleSignalEvents(Events event)
{
    switch (event)
    {
    case Events::AddEntryButton:
        m_eventHandler.HandleAddEntryClick(m_ui->addEntryDateEdit, m_ui->addEntryTextEdit, m_ui->mainEntryList);
        break;
    }

}
```

The EventHandler-class:

```
void EventHandler::HandleAddEntryClick(QDateTimeEdit *dateTimeEdit, QTextEdit *textEdit, QListWidget *mainList)
{
    QDate dateTime = dateTimeEdit->date();
    int day = dateTime.dayOfWeek();
}
```

The error I get is following (My visual studio is set to german language, but I try to translate it so it doesn't lose its meaning):

```
Exception at 0x... (Qt5Core.dll) in ... .exe:

0xC0000005: Access violated while reading at position 0x8B0C43BD
```

This happens at the moment I try to access `dateTimeEdit->date();`

Comment: What/when is the error exactly ? NB you're not using the `ui` argument in the handler but `m_ui` directly.

Comment: @Ilya my bad, I still had the code from a version where I tested a solution someone mentioned. Error is in as well now

Comment: Looks like `m_ui->addEntryDateEdit` is invalid (not a pointer to a created `QDateTimeEdit`)

Comment: Yes, it is indeed invalid, but now I don't know how to get the valid pointer to the method

Comment: It's a widget, not a method ...?

Comment: Oh, no, I mean how to get the valid pointer for the widget to the method handling it

Comment: Look at the setupUi method in the ui_*.h file (you're calling it, right ?).

Comment: I didn't really mess around with that file at all, if I would use it somehow, that would be rather automatically.

Comment: Yes it's automatic except that you have to call `setupUi`, and looking in the file helps to understand the logic if it's not clear (the code here is similar to the code you'd be writing by hand).

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to capture this, and then passing the whole ui pointer to the
>   HandleSignalEvent function, but all I ever end with is a memory access
>   violation assertion.

I'd try to pass the `m_ui` pointer by value to the event handler:

```
connect(m_ui->addEntryButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [=](){HandleSignalEvents(Events::AddEntryButton, m_ui);});
```

Comment: This way, I am constantly confronted with an error around 'BOOST_SP_INTERLOCKED_INCREMENT'... I guess something is malfunctioning with the reference counter of the shared-ptr

Comment: BTW why are you using Boost pointers and not a Qt shared ptr class ?

Comment: What happens if you pass `m_ui.get()` and use the raw pointer in the handler ?

Comment: I didn't even know it had its own smart pointers. I'm still in the learning process. Passing the raw pointer leads to no difference, I am still getting memory access violations

Comment: Not sure why, might be unrelated. Could you try setting m_ui as a member of `UIController` ?

Comment: it already is, it's a private member in the form of a boost::shared_ptr

Comment: So you don't need to pass it as a parameter to the handler, and the problem is elsewhere. Please add more info, what/when is the failure message exactly ?

Comment: Alright, I think the most related things are in my original post. Thanks for your effort so far!

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking a method on an object, so you must insure that the target object exists when the signal is emitted. You do this by providing the target object as the *context* to the connection.

This will work, or be a no-op if the target object has vanished:

```
connect(m_ui->addEntryButton, &QPushButton::clicked, 
        this, [this]{ HandleSignalEvents(Events::AddEntryButton); });
        ^^^^
        Absolutely critical
```

Furthermore, in the `UIController::HandleSignalEvents`, there's a likelihood that some `m_ui` members are null or are dangling pointers. Ensure that's not the case!

Note that `[&]{ ... }` captures `this` by value, as it should - capturing it by reference is nonsense as `this` would be out of scope when the method exits; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16323032/1329652) for details.

Comment: The way you proposed is not triggering the handler method at all :(

Comment: @Sossenbinder Then your problem is in the code you don't show. Please fix your question to make it possible to answer it :)