# 'this' pointer changes in c++11 lambda

Tags: pointers, c++11, lambda

I found a very strange problem with this pointer in c++11's lambda.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

boost::signals2::signal<void()> sig;

struct out {
    void print_something() {
        cout << "something" << endl;
    }
    out() {
        auto start = [&] {
            cout << "this in start: " << this << endl;
            this->print_something();
        };

        cout << "this in constructor: " << this << endl;

        // sig.connect(start);
        sig.connect([&] {
            cout << "this in signal: " << this << endl;
            start();
        });
        this->print_something();
    }
};

int main() {
    out o;
    sig();
}
```

The code prints three this(s) pointer at different location. I was expecting that all the three this pointer should be the same value, but they are not. Here's the output:

```
this in constructor: 00F3FABB
something
this in signal: 00F3FABB
this in start: 00F3FB00
something
```

**Question 1**: Why is `this in start` has different value? How to correct it?

**Question 2**: Since the `this in start` is a different pointer, it shouldn't be able to call `print_something()`. I would expect a crash on this but it works fine. Why?

Comment: You are capturing the this pointer by reference

Comment: @JustSid: `this` is [always captured by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16323032/56338), even with `[&]`.

Comment: @sth Ha! The more you know, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You capture `start` by reference, but the variable `start` and the contained lambda function get destroyed at the end of `out()`.

Later the signal handler tries to call `start()`, but the lambda function doesn't exist anymore. Maybe the memory where its `this` was stored was overwritten in the mean time, causing unexpected output.

The call to `print_something()` doesn't crash despite of the invalid `this` because the function doesn't actually try to use `this`. The printing in the function is independent of `this` and the lookup of `print_something`s address can happen at compile time so that calling the function doesn't access `this` at runtime.