# Using lambda in default initializer gcc vs clang

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, language-lawyer, member-initialization

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    struct point_of_cone
    {
        double x, y;
        double z = [&] { using std::sqrt; return sqrt(x * x + y * y); }();
    };
    point_of_cone p = {3.0, 4.0};
    assert(p.z == 5.0);
}
```

Works fine for `clang++` from trunk, but for `g++` from trunk fails with error message ([link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/n818z48nMp9OlALf)):

> error: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function

Definition of `point_of_cone` in namespace scope works fine for both.

Slightly modified definition with `[this]` lambda capture works fine also for both in either global or local scope.

Which compiler is right?

Comment: post that code in your question, please

Comment: @Orient No, I was referring to xaxxon's godbolt link, where he set the wrong flag.

Comment: Hmm the question is should `[&]` capture `this`. Not sure about new standards but the answer here suggest not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323032/why-cant-i-capture-this-by-reference-this-in-lambda

Comment: @Hayt &this is different.

Comment: @xaxxon where is `[&this]` meantioned? I meant if the default capture `[&]` would include `this` or not.

Comment: @Hayt "If a lambda-capture includes a capture-default that is &, no identifier in a simple-capture of that lambda-capture
shall be preceded by &. If a lambda-capture includes a capture-default that is =, each simple-capture of that
lambda-capture shall be of the form “& identifier” or “* this”. **[ Note: The form [&,this] is redundant
but accepted for compatibility with ISO C++ 2014. — end note ]**"  I don't completely understand that whole section, but the comment makes it clear that [&] captures this

Comment: Yeah I was not sure about this too, but this seems to indicate [&] should capture this.

Comment: @orient why did you delete the comment with the actual source code that reproduces the error without editing your question to include it?

Comment: @xaxxon The link was placed in the main question text, as you suggested.

Comment: @xaxxon Is it better to post whole code from the link?

Comment: @Orient your question should have all the code necessary to reproduce your question

Comment: @xaxxon It is done.

Comment: @Orient thank you :)   This helps other people that have a problem know if they have the same problem or not more quickly.  And the question is still good even if the question link dies for some reason.

Comment: (The operator in the assert is dangerous - 4.0 can be represented exactly…)

Comment: @greybeard 3.0, 4.0 and 5.0 has exact representation. There is no problem. Comparison with tolerance can complicate example.

Comment: `There is no problem` as in 9.0, 16.0, 25.0 have exact representations, and the result of std::sqrt(25.0) is _guaranteed_ to be exact? I would need to read up on C++, if&when necessity arises.

Comment: @greybeard I think it is about IEEE 754.

Comment: That would indeed require it to be exact - used to be the only function in addition to the operators such constrained, seems to have been joined by _fused multiply-add_ since. (And might suggest using `hypot()`.)

Comment: @greybeard What do you think? Should I change `double` to `int` to make example better?

Comment: (from an off-handed remark to such trickiness) `Should I change double to int to make example better?` Or even pick a different example altogether that doesn't try to compare results of transcendental functions for equality, seeing the example is to illustrate capturing in a lambda, and the length of this exchange about [comparing doubles for equality](http://stackoverflow.com/a/77735/3789665). On a side note: `hypot()` avoids `undue overflow or underflow at intermediate stages`, but I can't seem to find an exactness required equivalent to `sqrt()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's a gcc bug.

```
int main() {
    struct A {
        int x, i = [&] { return x; }();
    } a{0};
}
```

This fails, but if we…

- change `&` to `this`, or
- declare `A` as having namespace scope,

it works. Neither of these should have any effect on the well-formedness, though.

Reported: [#78019](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78019).

Comment: If this is the same bug I've wandered into several times recently, then another workaround for it is to explicitly say `this->`.

Comment: @Griwes Could you have used the contrapositive to deduce that this isn't the bug you've wandered into? :-)