# Use std::function as member function, which capture `this`, and access it from the copied lambda after destructor

Tags: c++, lambda, temporary-objects

[Flex Ferrum](https://twitter.com/flex_ferrum) post a code sample [here](https://twitter.com/flex_ferrum/status/1004818468246519808) (I think it is **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable** enough):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class Bang
{
public:
    Bang(int i = 0) : m_val(i)
    {
        m_foo = [this] {std::cout << m_val << std::endl;};
    }

    ~Bang()
    {
        m_val = -1;
    }

    void Foo()
    {
        m_foo();
    }
private:
    int m_val;
    std::function<void ()> m_foo;
};

Bang GetBang()
{
    return Bang(100500);
}

int main() {
    Bang b(100500);
    b.Foo();
    b = GetBang();
    b.Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Our nice Flex also offer a [**`live demo`**](https://www.ideone.com/jJexu7)

---

After a rough look, I thought it will output `100500`, but the real output is:

```
-1
```

- Why? What's behind it?
- How to fix it?(output `100500`, not `-1`)

<sub>I have written some my own reasonings in the `ask box`, but found it is more fit to be posted as an answer(will make the question too long). If my answer is wrong, please correct it and more answers are welcome</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, it should blame the destructor of temporary - `Bang(100500)`, which returns form `GetBang`, is [`prvalue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue), and has [`temporary object lifetime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime).

1. [`[this]` will be stored as reference of `*this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323032/why-cant-i-capture-this-by-reference-this-in-lambda/47678549#47678549), like this:

---

```
    class Lambda
    {
    public:
        void operator()() const
        {
            //output
        }

    private:
        Bang& bang;

    public:
        Lambda(Bang& bang) : bang{bang}
        {
        }

    } lambda{*this};
    ...
    m_foo = lambda;
```

---

2. Because here is **no** `RVO`, so, the temporary `Bang(100500)` will first be assigned to  `b`, then be destroyed.
3. Custorm `operator()`, `constructor`, and `destructor` to output some information:

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Bang
{
public:
    Bang(int i = 0) : m_val(i)
    {

        std::cout << "Bang(int i = 0) m_val address is " << &m_val << '\n';
        class Lambda
        {
        public:
            void operator()() const
            {

                std::cout << "operator() m_val address is " << &bang.m_val << '\n';
                std::cout << bang.m_val << std::endl;
            }

        private:
            Bang &bang;

        public:
            Lambda(Bang &bang) : bang{bang}
            {
            }

        } lambda{*this};
        m_foo = lambda;

    }

    ~Bang()
    {
        std::cout << "~Bang()\n";
        m_val = -1;
    }

    void Foo()
    {
        m_foo();
    }

private:
    int m_val;
    std::function<void()> m_foo;
};

Bang GetBang()
{
    return Bang(100500);
}

int main()
{
    Bang b;
    b = GetBang();
    b.Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

---

[**`live demo`**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mTMZnTzFcJESn5ki)

Output:

```
Bang(int i = 0) m_val address is 0x7ffd202c48b0
Bang(int i = 0) m_val address is 0x7ffd202c48e0
~Bang()
operator() m_val address is 0x7ffd202c48e0
-1
~Bang()
```

shows:

- `dtor` will be called before output, That means that the temporary object has been destroyed.
- `m_value`'s address doesn't change.

The two guaranteed we still access the temporary's `m_value` from the `b`'s `m_foo()`.

It should be **Undefined Behaviour** to access an object which has be destroyed, but no warning and errors required.

### Update

To solve the problem, there two solutions:

1. Like [*@Killzone Kid*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50773561/6949852) points out, capture with an initializer: `[bang = *this]`. This requires c++14.
2. More simpler way to capture of the current object by-copy: `[*this]`. This requires c++17. [**`live demo`**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Zl8RXjXDDwZPIbmi)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to pass current object to lambda by value `*this` so that it can be stored and copied when you copy assign `Bang`. Passing pointer `this` will store and copy pointer to the temp object that has been destroyed when you copy assign `Bang`.

This works as it should:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Bang
{
public:
    Bang(int i = 0) : m_val(i)
    {
        m_foo = [bang = *this] { std::cout << bang.m_val << std::endl; };
    }

    ~Bang()
    {
        m_val = -1;
    }

    void Foo()
    {
        m_foo();
    }
private:
    int m_val;
    std::function<void()> m_foo;
};

Bang GetBang()
{
    return Bang(100500);
}

int main()
{
    Bang b;
    b = GetBang();
    b.Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/LUDrBb