# In C++, capturing " *this " in lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14, c++17

```
struct S { 
    int x = 4;
    void f(int i); 
};

void S::f(int i) {
    [=, *this]{}; // OK: captures this by value. See below.
}
```

Why is the lambda `[=, *this]{};` valid?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323032/why-cant-i-capture-this-by-reference-this-in-lambda

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "OK" or "valid". This code [does not in fact compile](https://rextester.com/ENS95979)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It's a [C++17 feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what do you mean, but [p0018r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0018r0.html) may answer your question:

> ### 2 Motivations for lambda capture of *this by Value
>
> Truly capturing *this by value allows an implicitly declared closure to be copied before invoking the closure's functon.
>
> #### 2.1 Asynchronous dispatch of lambda
>
> Asynchronous dispatch of closures a cornerstone of parallelism and concurrency.
>   When a lambda is asynchronously dispatched from within a non-static member function, via std::async or other concurrency / parallelism dispatch mechanism, the enclosing *this class cannot be captured by value. Thus when the future (or other handle) to the dispatched lambda outlives the originating class the lambda's captured this pointer is invalid.
>
> ```
> class Work {
> private:
>   int value ;
> public:
>   Work() : value(42) {}
>   std::future<int> spawn()
>     { return std::async( [=]()->int{ return value ; }); }
> };
>
> std::future<int> foo()
> {
>   Work tmp ;
>   return tmp.spawn();
>   // The closure associated with the returned future
>   // has an implicit this pointer that is invalid.
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>   std::future<int> f = foo();
>   f.wait();
>   // The following fails due to the
>   // originating class having been destroyed
>   assert( 42 == f.get() );
>   return 0 ;
> }
> ```
>
> #### 2.2   Dispatching asynchronous closures to data
>
> Current and future hardware architectures specifically targeting parallelism and concurrency have heterogeneous memory systems. For example, NUMA regions, attached accelerator memory, and processing-in-memory (PIM) stacks. In these architectures it will often result in signficantly improved performance if the closure is copied to the data upon which it operates, as opposed to moving the data to and from the closure.
>
> For example, parallel execution of a closure on large data spanning NUMA regions will be more performant if a copy of that closure residing in the same NUMA region acts upon that data. If true a (self-contained) capture-by-value lambda closure were given to a parallel dispatch, such as in the parallelism technical specification, then the library could create copies of that closure within each NUMA region to improve data locality for the parallel computation. For another example, a closure dispatched to an attached accelerator with separate memory must be copied to the accelerator's memory before execution can occur. Thus current and future architectures require the capability to copy closures to data.
>
> #### 2.3   Onerous and error-prone work-around
>
> A potential work-around for this deficiency is to explicitly capture a copy the originating class.
>
> ```
> class Work {
> private:
>   int value ;
> public:
>   Work() : value(42) {}
>   std::future<int> spawn()
>     {
>       return std::async( [=,tmp=*this]()->int{ return tmp.value ; });
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> This work-around has two liabilities. First, the this pointer is also captured which provides a significant opportunity to erroneously reference a this-> member instead of a tmp. member. Second, it is onerous and counter-productive to the introduction of asynchronously dispatched lambda expressions within existing code. Consder the case of replacing a for loop within a non-static member function with a parallel for each construct as in the parallelism technical specification.
>
> ```
> class Work {
> public:
>   void do_something() const {
>     // for ( int i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i )
>     foreach( Parallel , 0 , N , [=,tmp=*this]( int i )
>     {
>       // A modestly long loop body where
>       // every reference to a member must be modified
>       // for qualification with 'tmp.'
>       // Any mistaken omissions will silently fail
>       // as reference
> ```