# If I use a lambda-exppr in a method then I want to call another method then should I capture `this` by value or by reference?

Tags: c++, foreach, lambda

For educational reasons I've decided to implement a class that simulates `std::string`.

- I have a method called `append` which I've implemented this way:

  ```
  template<class T, class U>
  inline String& String::append(T b, U e)
  {
      std::for_each(b, e, [this](char c) {push_back(c); }); // [&] or this?

      return *this;
  }
  ```

So I need to access `this` pointer inside the lambda-exppr so should I capture `this` by value or by reference? ** if by value then it works fine also.

Comment: `[&]` and `[this]` are equivalent. You can capture the current object by value by using `[*this]` but that is not what you want here.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16323032

Comment: Why use a lambda at all? `std::copy(b, e, std::back_inserter(*this))`

Comment: @Kerndog73: yea really amazing.